# How to get back informations about location or state from coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web, google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap

I'm working on web application where i should be able to retreive informations of a specific place using only geo coordinates.Eg . I have a `latitude` and a `longitude` that are given and known but no other informations about the country,state,city,etc.Is it possible to retreive informations about the `country,state,city` with a kind of `API` that takes `latitude` and a `longitude`as params and return some raw `json` that contains `country,state,city` of a given place?

Comment: For OSM see [search engines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) aka geocoding services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of APIs for this. Google for "reverse geocoding".

Example:

[Google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding)